# How to change loop direction

Tags: java, for-loop

I have 3x3 stars cube, but I make it can print continue as we want from our input, **BUT** it's loop Will go **down**, not go **right**, how to change to loop to the **right**

```
import java.util.scanner;

Public class program {
    Public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner getInp;
        int a;
        
        getInp = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = getInp.nextInt();

        for (int x=0; x<a; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<3; y++) {
                for (int z=0; z<3; z++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why 3rd loop for 3x3 grid??

Comment: B'cause to make 3x3 cube loopable and setable number of Loops by user

Comment: what do you mean it doesnt go right??? I dont understand what you are trying to get at. the print() is not println so it should continue on to the right?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you want to print  a number of 3x3  cubes, like

```
* * *.   * * *.  * * *
* * *.   * * *.  * * *
* * *.   * * *   * * *
```

If this is the case then you have to change the line after the second inner loop which is the y one.
Because you can print only line by line.

```
Scanner getInp;
        int a;
        
        getInp = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = getInp.nextInt();

        for (int x=0; x<a; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<3; y++) {
                for (int z=0; z<3; z++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
System.out.println("\n"):
        }
```

Try this if that's the case ..